# Why the below command prints nothing as output?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Why does the following command print nothing as output?

```
ls -ltr > awwk | cat awwk |awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Could it be that your directory is empty? Does `ls` give any output?

Comment: no directory is not empty...awwk file has been created with the above command..but still it displays no output

Answer (score 8):

When you do

```
ls -ltr > awwk | cat awwk
```

both `ls` and `cat` run concurrently. Since `cat` doesn't wait for `ls` to finish, its likely to try to read from the file before `ls` has written anything into it, so it gets an empty input.

You don't need to use a pipe if you're writing to a file and then reading from it. You can the commands sequentially:

```
ls -ltr > awwk
awk '{print $1}' < awwk # No need to use cat here
```

Or you may not need the file at all, just pipe directly from one command to the next:

```
ls -ltr | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following instead,

```
ls -ltr > awwk; cat awwk | awk '{ print $1}'
```